# AngularJS ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a table of data that I'm trying to access via ng-repeat.  I think I've got everything correct in my code, but when I load the page the data doesn't load.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is my table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" 
       ng-repeat="sale in vm.sales">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>
            Date Ordered
        </th>
        <th>
            Retail
        </th>           
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ sale.dateOrdered }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ sale.firstLoadRetail}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Subtotal
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  .controller('ReportCtrl', ReportCtrl);


function ReportCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.sale = [
        {
            dateOrdered: '05/10/2015',
            firstLoadRetail: '75',
            firstLoadCost: '65',
            instantProfitAirTime: '9',
            instantProfitSpiff: '59',
            netRetail: '75',
            netCost: '7',
            netProfit: '67',
            count: '0',
            billAmount: '45'
        },
        {
            dateOrdered: '06/22/2015',
            firstLoadRetail: '85',
            firstLoadCost: '75',
            instantProfitAirTime: '10',
            instantProfitSpiff: '86',
            netRetail: '22',
            netCost: '8',
            netProfit: '22',
            count: '0',
            billAmount: '35'
        }
    ];
}
```

I'm getting the error message Argument 'report.controller' is not a function, got undefined.  Last time I got this error message I had a typo, but I'm not seeing any typos in my code this time.

Comment: Where are you assigning the controller to the view?

Comment: Also I think you are not using $scope service

Comment: I actually didn't build this project, and so new to angular that I don't completely understand how some of it works, but vm is used in place of $scope, and in all of the other pages ng-controller is not used.  Even when I do at it to my page though I get the same error message.  I'm sorry about my lack of knowledge.  I just learned Angular and got thrown into this super big program written by someone who was a wiz with Angular and is no longer here.

Comment: This code is missing the line where you declare `ng-controller` and assign `vm`, this line would seem to be the line the error you are describing is coming from.  This isn't a ***complete*** example of your code.  note that the `vm` might be assigned in a router provider, and not in the HTML here.

Comment: either way, this error is describing `report.controller` as an invalid argument, but this isn't the area of the code base where `report.controller` is used.  have you searched for `report.controller` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check below working code snippet -

```js
angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.sales = [
        {
            dateOrdered: '05/10/2015',
            firstLoadRetail: '75',
            firstLoadCost: '65',
            instantProfitAirTime: '9',
            instantProfitSpiff: '59',
            netRetail: '75',
            netCost: '7',
            netProfit: '67',
            count: '0',
            billAmount: '45'
        },
        {
            dateOrdered: '06/22/2015',
            firstLoadRetail: '85',
            firstLoadCost: '75',
            instantProfitAirTime: '10',
            instantProfitSpiff: '86',
            netRetail: '22',
            netCost: '8',
            netProfit: '22',
            count: '0',
            billAmount: '35'
        }
    ];

 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">



<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" ng-repeat="sale in sales">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>
            Date Ordered
        </th>
        <th>
            Retail
        </th>           
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ sale.dateOrdered }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ sale.firstLoadRetail}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Subtotal
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will solve you problem!

Comment: I changed it to vm.sales, still getting the same error message.

Comment: @hollyquinn - Check Edited answer for working copy of the code. Hope this will solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Issues seems to be that you have the variable name as vm.sale in controller and looping thru vm.sales in html (extra s)

Comment: I changed this.  Now I've got  vm.sales in the controller and ng-repeat="sale in vm.sales" in the view.  Still getting the same error message.