# difficulty running ng-repeat for an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a block of html code which I would like to repeat for each object in an array of objects, where each object would populate a section like such...

```
<!--  -->
<!-- Future appointments section -->
<!--  -->
<div class="future-appointments-meta-holder" ng-repeat="person in vm.myData">

 <div class="future-appointments-holder">
   <div class="future-appointments-info-holder">
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text">
       {{vm.myData[person].activeReferralsType}}
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-secondary">
       {{vm.myData[person].activeReferralsDate}} | {{vm.myData[person].activeReferralsTime}}
     </p>
   </div>

   <div class="future-appointments-info-holder-mid">
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       <b>{{vm.myData[person].referredFromName}}</b>
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       {{vm.myData[person].referredFromAddressFacilityName}}
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       {{vm.myData[person].referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineOne}}
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       {{vm.myData[person].referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo}}, {{vm.myData[person].referredFromAddressFacilityAddressState}} {{vm.myData[person].referredFromAddressFacilityAddressZip}}
     </p>
   </div>

   <div class="future-appointments-info-holder-right2">
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       PUBLIC | {{vm.myData[person].referredFromPublicNum}}
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       BACK | {{vm.myData[person].referredFromBackNum}}
     </p>
     <p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-col2">
       DOCTOR | {{vm.myData[person].referredFromDocNum}}
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="horizontal-rule">

 </div>
</div>
<!--  -->
<!-- END future appointments section -->
<!--  -->
```

My dataset looks something like this

```
vm.myData = [
          {
            "alert": "2"
            , "activeReferralsType" : "new patient diabetic eye exam"
            , "activeReferralsDate" : "September 30, 2017"
            , "activeReferralsTime" : "2:00PM"
            , "referredFromName" : "Karen Rush, MD"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityName" : "Random Family Practice"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "1108 Cedar Road"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "Chesapeake"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressState" : "VA"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressZip" : "90210"
            , "referredFromPublicNum" : "218.202.4561"
            , "referredFromBackNum" : "218.556.4568"
            , "referredFromDocNum" : "218.555.5555"
            , "referredToName" : "Karen Rush, MD"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityName" : "Random Family Practice"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "1108 Cedar Road"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "Chesapeake"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressState" : "VA"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressZip" : "90210"
            , "referredToPublicNum" : "218.202.4561"
            , "referredToBackNum" : "218.556.4568"
            , "referredToDocNum" : "218.555.5555"

          },
          {
            "alert": "3"
            , "activeReferralsType" : "new patient diabetic eye exam"
            , "activeReferralsDate" : "Ontober 22, 2017"
            , "activeReferralsTime" : "1:00PM"
            , "referredFromName" : "Mark Spencer, MD"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityName" : "Medical Life Practice"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "666 Road Way"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "Houston"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressState" : "TX"
            , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressZip" : "39405"
            , "referredFromPublicNum" : "218.900.3333"
            , "referredFromBackNum" : "218.111.0000"
            , "referredFromDocNum" : "218.445.2135"
            , "referredToName" : "Gul Dukat, MD"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityName" : "St. Vincent Hospital"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "1 Hosipital Road"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "New York"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressState" : "NY"
            , "referredToAddressFacilityAddressZip" : "33330"
            , "referredToPublicNum" : "218.552.2131"
            , "referredToBackNum" : "218.555.1234"
            , "referredToDocNum" : "218.555.5555"

          }
        ];
```

I have read through the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) and looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548400/how-to-get-the-next-item-in-ng-repeat-for-an-object), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864706/angular-ng-repeat-not-working), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152883/angularjs-ng-repeat-not-working) stack questions, but I simply do not understand how the ng-repeat works. Do I just have a syntax issue? or is it a wider misunderstanding of the concept?

Comment: also, you should use a track by statement for you ng-repeats for performance.

Comment: will definately add that in. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `person` instead of `vm.myData[person]` inside your `ng-repeat` div.
Essentially the `ng-repeat` will repeat whatever you have inside that HTML element for each element of the array `myData` where you can use each element as `person` where you defined in `ng-repeat="person in vm.myData"`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` attribute is like a `for` loop. In your situation `vm.myData` is an array of objects. Therefore doing `<div ng-repeat="person in vm.myData">` will make you access each object using `person`. So, now you can do `{{ person.activeReferralsType }}` as an example.

Hope this helps.